# How can I execute INSERT INTO SELECT with DEFAULT for primary key?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, rdbms

I am trying to copy distinct values from one table column into another table column. However, I encounter issues when trying to create primary keys for new records.

Database: PostgreSQL on AWS RDS

---

```sql
INSERT INTO target (name)
SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM source
WHERE source.field_name IS NOT NULL
RETURNING *;
```

Executing this results in an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" of relation "target" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, mydummyfieldname).
```

All my research leads me to something like the following:

```sql
INSERT INTO target (id, name)
VALUES (DEFAULT, 'name1'), (DEFAULT, 'name2')
```

However, it is not obvious to me how I can use `DEFAULT` with the `SELECT` clause.

**Question:** How can I use `DEFAULT` with the `SELECT` clause in raw SQL?

I am not permitted to modify the primary key of either table to use `serial` or something like that.

---

Table definitions (using SQLAlchemy ORM)

```py
class Source(Base):

    id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
    )
    field_name = Column(
        String,
        nullable=False,
    )


class Target(Base):

    id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
    )
    name = Column(
        String,
        nullable=False,
        unique=True,
    )
```

Comment: just a clarification, do you need a raw sql that somehow uses default or do you need some changes to your ORM models? It is unclear *to me* why you would show the ORM model if you wanted raw sql

Comment: The SQL you show at the top of you question does not produce the error you list below it.

Comment: @python_user: Ah, sorry. I will edit the original post. I am requesting a raw SQL statement that uses DEFAULT. I do not need changes to my ORM models, nor can I change them. I posted the ORM models for context, specifically to highlight `default=uuid.uuid4`.

Comment: @RichardHuxton ...indeed it does? I am looking at the error at this exact moment.

Comment: @AndrewParsons IIRC the default you set is at python level and not on postgres, something like `INSERT INTO target (id, name) select gen_random_uuid(), * from (SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM source WHERE source.field_name IS NOT NULL) _ RETURNING *;`? there are probably better optimized ways

Comment: @python_user Thank you! I naïvely thought that the the default set in the ORM corresponded to the PostgreSQL-level default. Your query appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

> The SQL you show at the top of you question does not produce the error
> you list below it. –  Richard Huxton

> @RichardHuxton ...indeed it does? I am looking at the error at this exact moment.

No it doesn't

```
richardh=> CREATE TABLE target (id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY, name text NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
richardh=> CREATE TABLE source (field_name text NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
richardh=> INSERT INTO source VALUES ('aaa');
INSERT 0 1
richardh=> INSERT INTO target (name) SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM source WHERE source.field_name IS NOT NULL RETURNING *;
                  id                  | name 
--------------------------------------+------
 27e8410d-fdea-4224-8e4d-5471e36f10a1 | aaa
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```

Your ORM isn't generating that query, or your table definitions don't have a default for the id. Always check the actual SQL and schema first.